# Silverlight custom panel: how to affect child height?

Tags: c#, silverlight, panel

my items in custom panel doesn't change their size, just clips.

I have panel sized to 400px height and listbox in it full of items (with scrollbar).

I would like to make that child to take only half of my panel's height like this in ArrangeOverride:

```
Children.Single().Arrange(
    new Rect(0, 0, child.DesiredSize.Width, finalSize.Height / 2));
```

At first it looks like that it worked well, but for real listbox's size didn't change its still 400px, but only top 200px are visible - it got clipped instead of resized.

I got more complicated panel but all items in it gets clipped. Any hints what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating custom panel it's Children size must be calculated in MeasureOverride method not in Arrange. Moving code from ArrangeOverride to MeasureOverride with some minor tweaks forced custom panel to function as intended.

Second parameter for Arrange must be not less than DesiredSize calculated in MeasureOverride method. If not - item will get clipped.

Answer (score 1):

Make a grid with two rows of * height, and put your listbox in the top one.  Make sure the scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbar / verticalscrollbar properties are not set to hidden and you should be fine.

Seems like you are trying to make this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I don't need grid. My question is how to affect child height in custom panel as it gets clipped. The problem with grid is that if my listbox would contain one item I would get a huge gap (half of screen empty) between listbox and next item (if I have 2 children).

Comment: Then why don't you just set the MaxHeight on the Element and then call Measure or Arrange without overrides.

Comment: MaxHeight can be set to pixels only. It cannot be set to *. Anyway in custom panel I could say that I need to use 90% of height for first child and 10% for the second depending on circumstances. My problem that those children get cut but not shrinked.

Comment: To go with my last comment, what I meant was to set MaxHeight in code using the same method you used in the question.  So something like `Children.Single().MaxHeight = finalSize.Height / 2`.  You would probably need to do a cast on the Children.Single() to ListBox.

Comment: UIElements (Children) are not objects with static size. Their sizes changes in time. So if I have two children like 50% and 50% at startup I could set their MaxHeight. But when one shrinks - ratio would become 60% to 40% but unfortunately the bigger won't expand because it's constrained by MaxHeight already. Also panel's SizeChanged won't fire. That's why I need to create custom panel as OverrideArrange executes on these circumstances.